# Is it possible to analyze the stats of Citus like we do in PostgreSQL for its index, query optimization. If yes, how?

Tags: postgresql, citus

I am familiar with using stat tables in postgresql to analyze indexes and queries, with the help of pg_stat_activity, pg_stat_statements, etc.
However, in citus where I have distributed tables, (please correct me if I am wrong) I believe the stats shown is for only the coordinator node. Is there any way i can analyze the citus stats for its optimization?

Comment: Does this answer your question "Citus propagates the ANALYZE command to all worker node placements."   https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v11.1/admin_guide/table_management.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding :) I tried using the ANALYZE command earlier but my table is bit large and while executing this command I get CPU alerts. I cancelled the query and could not analyze the result. And more than that i wanted to use commands like below, to find the unused indexes (in citus it does not give exact result).
`SELECT
           indrelid::regclass tab_name,pi.indexrelid::regclass
             unused_index
           FROM
           pg_index pi, pg_stat_user_indexes psui
           WHERE pi.indexrelid=psui.indexrelid AND NOT indisunique AND
             idx_scan=0;`